# Bad wifi signals in ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, wireless

I dual booting ubuntu 22.04 LTS with windows, I noticed that remote Wi-Fi networks no longer appear, on the contrary, for Windows, in Windows, remote networks appear and work well, when I share my phone's Wi-Fi, it appears, but when I move away a little, the network disappears